# Identify whether JDialog is already opened

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

How do I identify whether a JDialog component is already opened or not, thus, it would avoid the same JDialog to be opened twice at the same application instance?

One solution I had in mind was to verify whether an object is already a JDialog instance (dialogObj instanceof JDialog), if so, I just call the method responsible for its construction / exhibition, if not, I just create a new JDialog instance (fill free to correct me if I'm delusional).

Let's suppose I've created a JDialog containing one (1) JPanel, one (1) JTextField, one (1) JButton and the element that holds the event who will "display" the JDialog every time is a  JMenuItem -> JPopUpMenu -> TrayIcon (System Tray icon).

I've almost discovered a way to solve it (as shown at the second paragraph), however, when I open it again through the System Tray, everything what I've typed before I've "disposed" the dialog box appears again, not to mention the others elements status that remains the same (JButton enabled etc - its another story).

Does anyone here have a clue how to solve it (of course it does)?

Comment: The same instance, or just in general?

Comment: good question +1, I voting http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isDisplayable%28%29

Comment: There is a problem. Every ActionEvent over the JMenuItem, responsible for show it, creates a new instance of the class that extends JDialog. As I said, I may verify if the object is a JDialog instance through "instanceof" but again, when I dispose and call it again the JTextField holds the last text I typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve both tasks as

- A) Init just ONE JDialog
- B) To check is it opened

You can simply use a modal JDialog as

```
JDialog aDialog=new JDialog();
aDialog.setModal(true);
```

...this won't let user to init another JDialog example :)

Good luck

Comment: It might be the answer I was looking for, but, to be honest, I thought it wouldn't be necessary to work with Modal feature to achieve the results I've wanted. Nonetheless, I don't known exactly whether this approach will fix the issue regarding the JTextField holds the text typed before the JDialog to be disposed. Anyway, thank you very much, I'll try and I let you known later on.

Comment: The concept I want for this specific app is similar that you may find when you interact with your antivirus app lying at the taskbar (system tray) in most cases pressing the mouse right button and choosing the available options.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't answer my own question due to the website regulation. I found the solution for my case. I appreciate everyone's effort to help me out, but, to fix this awkward issue, I've just "break" the JDialog heritage, adding within a void method both JDialog object's declaration and instanciation.

Comment: I just suggested to use the standard "modal" option as for JDialog and that is the most easy way to get the result you describe in your question. But if you want to keep JFrame accessable you can still make a "new" "Object" which extends JDialog and set there new rules for your "Object"... For example you can catch whether the "Object" inited and prevent user to init another example but it is much longer way though

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the JDialog instance, then you can simply call isVisible().  If it is showing, this will be true.

Comment: Understood. This procedure may resolve the issue regarding the JDialog to be shown twice when I interact with the JMenuItem responsible for its exhibition. However, once the dialog window is closed (dispose()) and I call it again through the TrayIcon -> JPopUpMenu -> JItemMenu its content is shown as it has never been "disposed", I mean, the text I've typed within the JTextField element appears again.

Comment: I tried to apply your suggestion but, in one hand, it solves the JDialog window's duplication issue. At other hand, the JTextField within the JDialog continues to hold the text I typed before the dialog window is disposed. I thought when WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE is used, the entire window (and its contents) would be deleted, nonetheless, as I've been seen it, it doesn't proceed this way (at least here).

Comment: Try implementing a WindowListener which will give you, amongst others, a windowClosing event.  When this is fired, empty the contents of your JTextField component.

Comment: It was I did but instead of using windowClosing I've used windowClosed (In my case I don't know which one would be the best choice between the two methods) .Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As a variation here is just another basis conception (not tested)...

```
public class MyDialog extends JDialog
{

private boolean isOpen;

public MyDialog()
{

  this.setOpenStatus(true) ;      

}

private void setOpenStatus(boolean isOpen)
{
 this.isOpen=isOpen;
}

public boolean isDialogOpen(){return this.isOpen;}

}
```

//somewhere in your base app deeps...

```
public class aClass{

private MyDialog aDialog;//field



public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{

  if(e.getActionCommand().equals("DIALOG_OPEN"))
{
    if(this.aDialog.isDialogOpen())
     {
       System.out.println("Dialog is opened"); return;
     }

    if(!this.aDialog.isDialogOpen())
    {
      this.aDialog=new MyDialog();
      this.aDialog.addWindowListener(...);
      //set JDialog options...
    }
}


}

}//end aClass
```

So it can be used as well

Good luck

Comment: Well thought. It's another approach I may use. Note: Forgive me for I haven't had rated yet, as soon as I get solved this issue , I'll do it.